# White screen after running Ionic 4 app in cordova

Tags: cordova, android-studio, ionic-framework

I am new in ionic.
When I started my first project in ionic 4 it worked perfectly with command
for web 
**ionic serve**
but in case of 
**ionic cordova run android** 
it shows nothing but white screen on emulator

Project Structure :

- I have only created home component
- ionic version 4
- angular version 6.0.0

Solutions I have tried

**1. Removing platform than adding it again**
ionic cordova -platform rm android
ionic cordova -platform add android

> Note :
>
> I have created project by adding simple blank template,
>           Than generated /home component. I need help as I have created so many things in this project. but could not run it on emulator.

If I miss anything than we can discuss.
Thank you.

Comment: check for the any errors in by inspecting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of android are you using?. If you are using Android 5, It's a know issue in ionic 4. Check this [link](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/15438)