# Ionic 4 App blank screen on Android 5.2.2

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a Ionic 4 app that works fine in Android > 6, but when I build for Android 5.2.2 appear a blank screen and not works... My Ionic info:

```
Ionic:

ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.12.0 (C:\Users\Jesús\AppData\Roaming>\npm\node_modules\ionic)
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.0.2
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.12.4
@angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.2.4
@angular/cli                  : 7.2.4
@ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.4.0

Cordova:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
Cordova Platforms     : android 5.2.2
Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 3.1.2, (and 9 other plugins)

System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Sdk)
NodeJS            : v8.9.1 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
npm               : 5.5.1
OS                : Windows 10
```

And my plugin list:

```
cordova-plugin-actionsheet 2.3.3 "ActionSheet"
cordova-plugin-datepicker 0.9.3 "DatePicker"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 2.0.1 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 4.0.1 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-globalization 1.11.0 "Globalization"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 3.1.2 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-network-information 2.0.1 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
cordova-sqlite-storage 3.2.0 "Cordova sqlite storage plugin - cordova-sqlite-storage plugin version"
mx.ferreyra.callnumber 0.0.2 "Cordova Call Number Plugin"
uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator 5.0.4 "Launch Navigator"
```

Comment: Did you try to debug it? Check webview console output as described here https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/ and attach to your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [White screen after running Ionic 4 app in cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53257106/white-screen-after-running-ionic-4-app-in-cordova)